# How to connect a Windows CE Ethernet device on ActiveSync Remote Display on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-ce, activesync, remoteview

I have  a device connected to my Windows 7 desktop pc via an Ethernet cable. My aim is to remotely view the device and control it from my pc. I have had this running on an XP computer but not on a Windows 7 machine. I have researched online to download  Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Cente which I have done. I can load the ActiveSync software however the two devices are not communicating on the remote viewer. I have also entered the correct IP addresses on both my desktop computer and Windows CE device.

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help me out.

Comment: Not programming related in any way.

Comment: What software are you using? With VirtualCE (my app), you can connect over ethernet or wifi without problems (ActiveSync is not needed).

Comment: @Filburt I believe this is slightly programming related as I'm using it for testing a system using automated scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted this problem by downloading [Windows Mobile Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10601) . Once I had downloaded this I ran the Active Sync Remote Display (ASRDisp.exe).

N.B I have to load Active Sync first and click ignore when the warning message appears, then I have to turn the device on.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is old, answered question.

Still, if anybody need answer for this doubt:

> I have a WinCE device connected to my Windows 7 desktop pc via an Ethernet
>   cable. My aim is to remotely view the device and control it from my
>   PC.

See [Remote Display of WEC7 device using Ethernet - Windows Embedded Compact 7](http://wec7.blogspot.in/2014/02/remote-display-of-wec7-device-using.html).